# how to display split action bar

Tags: android

In the android [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home) they said to use split actionbar,

```
<manifest ...>
    <activity uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" ... >
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                   android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
    </activity> </manifest>
```

this what I did , but its not displaying

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.i.www.i" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
        <activity android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The split action bar pattern was discontinued with Android 5.0's `Theme.Material` and recent editions of `appcompat-v7`.

You are welcome to create your own `Toolbar` and place it at the bottom of your layout, as a split action bar replacement. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Toolbar/SplitActionBarCompat) has an `appcompat-v7` version of that approach, while [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Toolbar/SplitActionBar) has a sample that uses the native API Level 21 edition of the `Toolbar`.

Comment: I am getting invalid toolbar ` Toolbar tb=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);` from where it is reading ?

Comment: @Moudiz: The `Toolbar` is in the layout resource, such as https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Toolbar/SplitActionBar/app/src/main/res/layout-v21/main.xml

Comment: hello how are you today? your example about toolbar was good , now I want to enter activity in those toolbar. should I use fragments? or you recmond another way? do you have a example written by you?

Comment: @Moudiz: I am sorry, but I do not understand what you are looking for. I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you explain **in detail** what you want.

Comment: I asekd a question related to it , can youcheck it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264195/is-there-another-way-to-handle-toolbar-beside-fragment