# is there another way to handle toolbar beside fragment?

Tags: android

I have created a `toolbar` with 2 buttons/actions

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtBytes;
    private Context mContext;
    ListView list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //initToolbars();
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
       // imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgImage);

        downloadImage();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        Toolbar tb=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        tb.inflateMenu(R.menu.main);
        tb.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                return (onOptionsItemSelected(item));
            }
        });
      //  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       // return true;
        return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
    }
```

main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/byme" android:title="by me"
        android:orderInCategory="101" app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/byusers" android:title="by users"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

now those toolbars doesnt do anything when they are touched ,just displays toast message. what I want is main activity to be attached to first button and I want to create new activity attached to second button

my question : is there another way to do that beside Fragment? I know that I can do that in fragment, what I am asking is there another way to handle that ?

Comment: If you want to start an activity, call `startActivity()`. I fail to see what the issue is here.

Comment: @CommonsWare in the toolbar I have `@+id/byme` and `@+id/byusers` ok ? I want when I click in one of them to have an activity. I can do that in fragments right?

Comment: You do not need to use fragments to call `startActivity()`. `startActivity()` is a method on `Context`; `Activity` inherits from `Context`.

Comment: then how to do that ? if want to have 2 different activity from the toolbar. if I click in first botton in toolbar I get an activity if i add the other button i got another acitivty. how to do that with startacitivity() ?

Comment: When the user clicks the first button, create an `Intent` identifying the first activity and call `startActivity()` using that `Intent`. When the user clicks the second button, create an `Intent` identifying the second activity and call `startActivity()` using that `Intent`.

Comment: Do you an answer or example describe how to do that? Thanks in advance